# Anonymous vs non-anonymous authentications/users in Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I have some basic doubt, what is the anonymous user and non-anonymous user.

The word anonymous mean no-name, that mean, without user/password can login/access.

I search online, I am getting bundles of matter but I am not able to clear exact what.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, Spring Security automatically creates an *org.springframework.security.core.Authentication* object which contains information about the user's identity and the performed authentication.

An Anonymous user is such a user which has been authenticated using the *org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter* and which has an instance of *org.springframework.security.authentication.of AnonymousAuthenticationToken* as its Authentication object.

Unlike other authentication methods supported by Spring Security, the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter doesn't require any credentials (like password, certificate) to authenticate the user, but always successfully passes.

The benefit of using the Anonymous authentication is that your application can always rely on availability of the Authentication object, as otherwise it would be null until the user authenticates using a regular method.

A non-anonymous user is any user who has been authenticated by any other than the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter method.

Comment: i understand a bit that anonymous can access with token instead of user/password credentials. am i right?

Comment: It doesn't even need any token. User can be authenticated as anonymous without anything at all = no token, password, ... is needed. Of course you typically restrict what exactly can be accessed by anonymously authenticated users in your access policies.